# Writing plugins to TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, plugins, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to write a new plugin to TortoiseSVN?

I want to write a plugin to do a ANALYSIS,Validations(Set of rules) of file before it is checked in , if it fails the file should not be committed and and a report should be generated.

If already plugins exist for TortoiseSVN where to look up them ?

Comment: IMHO, this looks like a job for server-side hook scripts. Client-side checks can be easily overridden even inadvertently (e.g., the developer commits from his IDE rather than TortoiseSVN).

Comment: BTW, the program is called *TortoiseSVN*, not Tortise SVN. Using the correct name will undoubtedly help you to google for third-party scripts.

Comment: Sorry @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, It was a typo. Thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run your test in e.g. a [pre-commit client-side hook script](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).

Or you could implement an [issue tracker plugin](http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/notes/issuetrackers.txt) and do your checking there.